# PHP Autoload x Include - Include é inseguro?

Tags: php, segurança

Estou tendo um problema com um trabalho recente, onde fui questionado sobre a segurança de um site em PHP desenvolvido. O mesmo sofreu diversos ataques de força bruta nesta última semana, e o responsável pelo projeto me questionou se eu utilizei includes, e se sim, que isto deveria ser trocado por autoloaders, pois via includes, é possível quebrar fluxos de proxy (?) e descobrir os diretórios de diversos arquivos, tornando a aplicação vulnerável.

Como sou totalmente leigo em algumas questões mais avançadas de segurança, gostaria de saber até que ponto isso procede. Eu utilizo autoloaders para carregamento de classes e dependências, porém, para meus templates/views (headers, footers, conteúdos em comum entre as páginas), sempre utilizei includes e requires, e nunca tive problemas desta magnitude. Se essa brecha realmente procede, como utilizar autoloader no meu exemplo abaixo? Pra mim, não faz o menor sentido.

Um exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <?php include_once("referencias.php"); ?>
        <title>Site</title>
    </head>
    <body id="home" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
        <?php include_once("header.php"); ?>
        <main>
            ...
        </main>
        <?php include_once("footer.php"); ?>
        <?php include_once("referencias-footer.php"); ?>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu não vejo como pode ser feito um ataque por escaneamento. Esse tipo de ataque só funciona se o programador fizer algo como `include_once($_GET['file']);`.Por outro lado existem muitos [relatos de brechas em autoloaders](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00GhYisszZpHmYN_CfJPWrG8JE8og%3A1586636324977&ei=JCaSXvqYO8Wu5OUP0_mjuA4&q=php+autoloader+vulnerability&oq=php+autoloader+vulnerability&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECCMQJ0oKCBcSBjEyLTE1NUoICBgSBDEyLTVQ1CBY3yZg9ChoAHAAeACAAdsDiAHMCZIBCTAuNC4xLjAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj6uqb0mOHoAhVFF7kGHdP8COcQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Comment: Agora você tem rever as configurações de segurança no servidor HTTP. Se está sofrendo ataques reiterados pode ser porque acharam alguma coisa.

Comment: Sim, estou revendo diversas coisas como sanitização, validações, csrf, bloqueio de ips, crowlers, etc. Mas este ponto em particular me chamou muito a atenção pois nunca tinha ouvido falar nada disso